# There is a way to see the physical location of reallocated disk sectors?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

Before SMART, you could just read the HDD, count the LBA position and guess what is on what position and display on a graph or something.

Now HDDs reallocate sectors on their own, and present to the OS as if the HDD is fine (except complaining with SMART).

I want to know what happened to a particular HDD, without disassembling it, for example maybe all reallocated sectors are in a pattern that suggest the head crashed, or that it was stuck after a power down, or something like that.

There is any way to do that on those HDDs without resetting SMART data?